# How to use external taxonomy with the data list and directory facility of nuxeo?

Tags: nuxeo

i though that a vocabulary was a special type of directory or that at list a directory could provide a source for a vocabulary. It seems not[Data List and directories](https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/How+to+Add+a+New+Vocabulary). What i want to acheive is to plug my taxonomy server into nuxeo. In other words, i would like nuxeo to use taxonomies that are defined externally. Isn't the directory abstraction meant for it ? The taxonomy server provide some rest service for external access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the directory abstraction is designed to abstract lists like yours. You need to implement a new Nuxeo component and implement a `org.nuxeo.ecm.directory.DirectoryFactory` and a `org.nuxeo.ecm.directory.Directory` as well as a `org.nuxeo.ecm.directory.Session`. It's not as easy as it should and involves a few classes, but it's quite feasible.

You can take as an example the SQL implementation in `nuxeo-platform-directory-sql` to get an idea if what's needed.